# Which template file to edit to edit homepage in Mystile

Tags: functions, themes, templates, woocommerce-offtopic

The homepage I'm using is not a static page, and I'm currently trying to add a content slider to it using master slider. 
I'm not too sure which file the homepage takes on as it's template, so I'm not sure where to put the PHP function for the slider.
What is the name of the template file that the homepage uses in Mystile?

Comment: This might be better aimed at theme's developers/support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most likely file is index.php

Comment: I've made a child theme - copied across index.php however none of my changes are showing on the site?